# Is there a reason str_replace doesn't work on this phrase

Tags: php, str-replace

I am trying to replace the following text

> options":{"icon": "color.php?tx=31c},

into

> options":{"icon": "color.php?tx=31*},

basically removing the 'c' and replacing it with an asterisk
and the php function i'm using is as simple as a str_replace. So my code is as follow

```
$str = 'options":{"icon": "color.php?tx=31c},';
$newStr = str_replace("c},","*},",$str);
```

but for some reason when i echo $newstr, the str_replace didn't replace anything. I tried with just c, it works. I tried with just the }, it works. But not together. Anyone has any idea?

Comment: I tried your code with the semicolon and it works just fine... is there any error log or additional code that may be the reason for this code to not work?

Comment: there's no error I just don't see the str_replace working and it could be worth noting that, there are multiple lines of the options.....}, in the string

Answer (score 1):

Semicolon (;) missing on first line. Should be:

```
$str = 'options":{"icon": "color.php?tx=31c},';
```

Comment: oops sorry i was typing that out of my head, corrected

Comment: Your code runs just fine... are you sure you are echoing $newStr and not $str?

Comment: i'm really dumbfounded been reloading from scratch and everything works except for that

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$str = 'options":{"icon": "color.php?tx=31c},';
$newStr = str_replace("c},","*},",$str);
echo $newStr;
```

This code works perfectly for me. See this link : https://ideone.com/wOTb8V

As you can see, the output is `options":{"icon": "color.php?tx=31*},`

Maybe you are trying to echo `$str` instead of `$newStr` ?

Comment: that's the thing i tried on fiddler and it works but when i tried on local it doesn't...anything else i should look at?